# Rails Spree products data migration to Magento

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, magento, migration, spree

my main doubt is that i have a spree shop that the client now wants all the product data (name, variants, descriptions, images) to be exported and ready to be imported to magento.

I tried using the gem datashift_spree and was able to get a csv with the main product information but wasn't able on adding there also the images filenames.

Am i missing some feature on the datashift gem to fetch the image names?

Does anyone know a good way of fetching all product information from spree?
Especially also the image filenames of each product.

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: Have you tried using the API? You could write a script to pull all the JSON data from there. OR you could write a ruby script and use ActiveRecord to grab all of the data from Spree's DB schema to the Magento's DB schema. Interesting to hear that someone is moving from Spree to Magento (its usually the other way around). Has their been a bad experience with it? If Spree isn't working out, have you tried [Solidus](http://solidus.io/)? This way you can keep using ruby instead of PHP.

Comment: I found it that it was easier to use sql on the spree database and grab all the product data i needed to the imported to Magento.
And yes, it was weird, we convinced the client to move from they initial magento setup to a new shop created from scratch on spree but then later they wanted to move back to magento and i got no other option than find a way to get all the products data. 
Never used Solidus but the problem here is that the clients say they are used to the admin dashboard of magento and all that. 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: you're welcome. Odd that they wanted the Magento admin. Solidus's admin is OK if you ask me. They're revamping Solidus's from what I hear.